# How to reset a p5.js sketch if it fails to load

Tags: javascript, p5.js

hello i have a sketch which basically pulls from a giant database of over 8,000 images to select an image. sometimes, an image will fail to load and its not feasible for me to go through all 8000 images and find which ones are causing my sketch to freeze on "Loading..."

i just want a way to reset the sketch if the image selected fails to load and just select the next image or a random image or placeholder image in case one fails to load, instead of it just hanging on a "Loading..." screen.

seems like a really simple thing but i can't find any simple solution. i tried making a script to check if "p5_loading" div exists after a Timeout period, but then i realized since the sketch wont load if its broken then my Timeout will never run out to be able to check if it is broken.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that `preload()` and `loadImage()` have some serious shortcomings in this regard. The way `preload()` works is that when you have it declared, p5.js wraps all of the `loadXXX()` functions with a function that increments a counter before actually calling the underlying `loadXXX()` function. Each `loadXXX()` function then decrements the preload counter, but only if the resource is loaded successfully. As a result, unless one resorts to accessing p5.js internals, there is no way to re-try or recover from an error during preload.

Additionally `loadImage()` does not have good error handling logic. The issue is that `loadImage()` first performs an `fetch()` request for the resource, and if that does not raise an error it creates a `Image` object and uses its `src` property to actually load the image data. The problem with that is that it doesn't check the response status code and the `Image` object does not generate detailed error information. I would go so far as to call this a defect in p5.js worth of filing a GitHub issue. As a consequence, any robust loader that uses `loadImage()` has to treat all load failures equally (as opposed to an intelligent solution that would treat 5xx errors and timeouts as retry-able, but treat 4xx errors as not worth retrying).

So, given the bad news, what could we do? Roll our own loading screen and use the somewhat suboptimal error handling from `loadImage()`:

```js
const availableImages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const loading = {};
const loaded = [];
const size = 50;
const maxRetries = 3;

let isLoading = true;

function robustLoad(success, failure) {
  // select a random image
  let ix = floor(random(0, availableImages.length));
  // remove that image from the list of available images
  let id = availableImages.splice(ix, 1)[0];
  
  console.log(`attempting to load image id ${id}`);
  function tryLoadImage(retryCount) {
    loading[id] = loadImage(
      `https://robustp5jspreload.kumupaul.repl.co/get-image?id=${id}`,
      () => {
        // success
        loaded.push(loading[id]);
        delete loading[id];
        success();
      },
      err => {
        console.warn(`error loading image ${id}`);
        console.log(err);
        if (retryCount < maxRetries) {
          console.log(`retrying image ${id}`);
          tryLoadImage(retryCount + 1);
        } else {
          // throw in the towel on this id
          delete loading[id];
          if (availableImages.length > 0) {
            robustLoad(success, failure);
          } else {
            failure();
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  tryLoadImage(0);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  background(200);
  textSize(48);
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
  text('Loading...', 10, 10);

  // attempt to load two random images
  let status = [false, false];
  for (let n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
    let currentN = n;
    robustLoad(
      () => {
        status[currentN] = true;
        if (status.every(v => v)) {
          // We're done loading.
          isLoading = false;
          drawBg();
          loop();
        }
      },
      () => {
        console.warn(`unable to load image ${currentN}`);
      }
    );
  }
}

function drawBg() {
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y += size) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += size) {
      image(loaded[i++ % loaded.length], x, y, size, size);
    }
    i = ++j;
  }
}

function draw() {
  if (!isLoading) {
    circle(mouseX, mouseY, 30);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Note: This example is not meant to be something you would just use as is. It is just an example of one possible implementation.

The source I'm loading image from is a proof of concept I made [on Replit](https://replit.com/@KumuPaul/RobustP5JsPreload) which returns 502 66% of the time. As a result it's theoretically that it will completely fail some percentage of the time.

Comment: One alternative would be to convert your sketch to instance mode, and in the error handler of `loadImage()` you could call `remove()` and then re-instantiate your sketch. The downside of that approach is that if you're loading a bunch of images you have to restart from zero, instead of recovering by retrying or skipping the one bad image.